# Yocto: INITSCRIPT_PARAMS not works as expected

Tags: yocto, init, sysv

I'm using yocto Krogoth(2.1) and this not works in my startup_1.0.bb:

```
INITSCRIPT_PARAMS = "start 98 S ."
```

**startup.sh** was copied into **/etc/init.d** but not linked to **/etc/rcS.d/S98startup.sh** after *bitbake core-image-minimal*

I googled solutions and even cheked some bb files which included INITSCRIPT_PARAMS in poky/meta, but none helpful info found.

Here is my startup_1.0.bb

```
DESCRIPTION = "System startup scirpt"
SRC_URI = "file://startup.sh file://COPYING"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM ="file://${WORKDIR}/COPYING;md5=6d2888401cbe657f56de1326f56e905c"

INITSCRIPT_NAME = "startup"
INITSCRIPT_PARAMS = "start 98 S ."

inherit update-rc.d

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}${INIT_D_DIR}
    install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/startup.sh ${D}${INIT_D_DIR}/startup.sh

    # install -d ${D}/etc/rcS.d
    # install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/startup.sh ${D}/etc/rcS.d/S98startup.sh
}
```

---

UPDATE:
It's about name matching and hardcode file name. I've fixed it as Fabian Knapp's tipped.

```
DESCRIPTION = "System startup scirpt"

LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM ="file://${WORKDIR}/COPYING;md5=6d2888401cbe657f56de1326f56e905c"

INITSCRIPT_NAME = "startup.sh"
INITSCRIPT_PARAMS = "start 98 S ."

SRC_URI = "file://${INITSCRIPT_NAME} file://COPYING"

inherit update-rc.d

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}/${INIT_D_DIR}
    install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/${INITSCRIPT_NAME} ${D}/${INIT_D_DIR}/${INITSCRIPT_NAME}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried renaming `startup.sh` to `startup` ?

Comment: Yeap! Thank you very very much!

It's the INITSCRIPT_NAME matching with do_install(), and I have changed them, it's works now. THANKS!

Comment: Nice. You can mark this answer as solution. Thank you.